# How to convert JSON to String without using JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, codemirror

I've a JSON object and I want to display it in Code Mirror. Code Mirror expects string only.
When I do JSON.stringify it screws up the values where it is an array instead of just string.

eg.
This is the output of JSON.stringify

```
{
     "version": "1.1",
     "sid": "ManagementService",
     "svcVersion": "0.1",
     "oid": "getCurrentStatsForServiceTypes",
     "params": {
          "serviceTypes": "[\"rest\", \"wsdl\", \"database\", \"rss\"]"
     }
}
```

I want output as...

```
{
  "version": "1.1",
    "sid": "ManagementService",
    "svcVersion": "0.1",
    "oid": "getCurrentStatsForServiceTypes",
    "params": {
      "serviceTypes":["rest", "wsdl", "database","rss"]
    }
}
```

In short I want to convert the Type from Object to String without affecting the value.

Update:
JSON Object is

```
{
  "version": "1.1",
    "sid": "ManagementService",
    "svcVersion": "0.1",
    "oid": "getCurrentStatsForServiceTypes",
    "params": {
      "serviceTypes":["rest", "wsdl", "database","rss"]
    }
}
```

I want the same as a string. Something like this should work.

```
'{
  "version": "1.1",
    "sid": "ManagementService",
    "svcVersion": "0.1",
    "oid": "getCurrentStatsForServiceTypes",
    "params": {
      "serviceTypes":["rest", "wsdl", "database","rss"]
    }
}'
```

> Blockquote

Comment: If your object really contains an array (as you suggest), your JSON.stringify is buggy.

Comment: [There's no such thing as "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

If your `serviceTypes` parameter is an array, it should serialize as you indicate you want it to serialize.  I have a feeling you are putting a string in that property, not an array.

When I stringify your object literal i get

```
"{"version":"1.1","sid":"ManagementService","svcVersion":"0.1","oid":"getCurrentStatsForServiceTypes","params":{"serviceTypes":["rest","wsdl","database","rss"]}}"
```

The array is not escaped, its an array.

Comment: This is the original JSON Object

{
                "version": "1.1",
                "sid": "ManagementService",
                "svcVersion": "0.1",
                "oid": "getCurrentStatsForServiceTypes",
                "params": {
               "serviceTypes": ["rest", "wsdl", "database","rss"]
              }
            }

If you do JSON.stringify in Firebug Console you will see Array is escaped.


Sorry but I don't see any way to format the code in my comment.

Comment: Just use ` char to make inline code. Like ` code ` (without spaces). When I put your object to `JSON.stringify()` in Firebug console it's ok, array isn't escaped (I've tried `test = {...}; JSON.stringify(test);` and direct `JSON.stringify({...});`.

Comment: I just tried what you mentioned in Firebug but I got different result. Array is escaped.

see this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/FOrux.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems your serviceTypes are no array but a string in your Object. Try this:

```
obj.params.serviceTypes = JSON.parse(obj.params.serviceTypes);
return JSON.stringify(obj);
```